# How to make list of random integers accumulated by program output?

Tags: python-3.x, list, int

I have code output accumulated integers, so how i can make list of that, I tried list(temp) but it says "argument of type 'int' is not iterable" how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options.  You could make a variable that is an empty list.
Then you can use .append(int) to grow your list.

```
randlist = []
for someloop:
    code that generates x
    randlist.append(x)
```